# How to change the Background color of selected item in the Navigation Drawer

Tags: android

I was working on Nav drawer on my app.
I have made the background of my nav drawer #000000(Black). Whenever I select any item the textcolor of text changes from #E44F50(Carrot Red) to black but I cant change the background color of the selected item.
All I want is to change the background color of selected Item from black to carrot red.

Here is the github link to my app-

https://github.com/manmeet-22/NewsSnips-app.git

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/drawer_item" //changing text color 
        app:itemTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance20"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/drawer_item"
        app:itemBackground="@drawable/drawer_selected_item" //trying to change backgroundcolor the same way
        app:menu="@menu/drawer"
        tools:context="com.androidexample.newssnips.app.NavigationDrawerFragment"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

In this I tried changing the background color like I did for the text but my app crashes.

here is my drawer_selected_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/colorAccent" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
</selector>
```

here is my drawer_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:color="@color/colorPrimary" android:state_checked="true" />
        <item android:color="@color/colorAccent" />
</selector>
```

Here is my MainActivity.java:

```
navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
        navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);
        Menu menu = navigationView.getMenu();

        //For chnaging the textColor and textSize of group's Name ie. Category
        MenuItem categoryName= menu.findItem(R.id.categoryGroup);
        SpannableString s = new SpannableString(categoryName.getTitle());
        s.setSpan(new TextAppearanceSpan(this, R.style.TextAppearance25), 0, s.length(), 0);

        //For changing the Text of action bar as the selected category
        categoryName.setTitle(s);

        //Setting Navigation View Item Selected Listener to handle the item click of the navigation menu
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

            // This method will trigger on item Click of navigation menu
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {


                //Checking if the item is in checked state or not, if not make it in checked state
                if (menuItem.isChecked())
                    menuItem.setChecked(false);
                else
                    menuItem.setChecked(true);

                //Closing drawer on item click
                drawerLayout.closeDrawers();

                //Check to see which item was being clicked and open the Appopriate news accordingly
                switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {

                    case R.id.itemWorld:
                        GAURDIAN_REQUEST_URL = "http://content.guardianapis.com/search?api-key=f51fa87d-8a55-4fc1-b552-8fa6eb98dee4&section=world";
                        setTitle("World News");

                        basicDefaults();
                        return true;
                    case R.id.itemFootball:
                        GAURDIAN_REQUEST_URL = "http://content.guardianapis.com/search?api-key=f51fa87d-8a55-4fc1-b552-8fa6eb98dee4&section=football";
                        setTitle("Football News");
                        basicDefaults();
                        return true;
                    case R.id.itemFashion:
                        GAURDIAN_REQUEST_URL = "http://content.guardianapis.com/search?api-key=f51fa87d-8a55-4fc1-b552-8fa6eb98dee4&section=fashion";
                        setTitle("Fashion News");
                        basicDefaults();
                        return true;
                    case R.id.itemSports:
                        GAURDIAN_REQUEST_URL = "http://content.guardianapis.com/search?api-key=f51fa87d-8a55-4fc1-b552-8fa6eb98dee4&section=sport";
                        setTitle("Sports News");
                        basicDefaults();
                        return true;
                    case R.id.itemBusiness:
                        GAURDIAN_REQUEST_URL = "http://content.guardianapis.com/search?api-key=f51fa87d-8a55-4fc1-b552-8fa6eb98dee4&section=business";
                        setTitle("Business News");
                        basicDefaults();
                        return true;
                    case R.id.itemTechnology:
                        GAURDIAN_REQUEST_URL = "http://content.guardianapis.com/search?api-key=f51fa87d-8a55-4fc1-b552-8fa6eb98dee4&section=technology";
                        setTitle("Technology News");
                        basicDefaults();
                        return true;
                    case R.id.itemOpinion:
                        GAURDIAN_REQUEST_URL = "http://content.guardianapis.com/search?api-key=f51fa87d-8a55-4fc1-b552-8fa6eb98dee4&section=commentisfree";
                        setTitle("Opinions");
                        basicDefaults();
                        return true;
                    case R.id.itemCulture:
                        GAURDIAN_REQUEST_URL = "http://content.guardianapis.com/search?api-key=f51fa87d-8a55-4fc1-b552-8fa6eb98dee4&section=culture";
                        setTitle("Culture News");
                        basicDefaults();
                        return true;
                    case R.id.itemTravel:
                        GAURDIAN_REQUEST_URL = "http://content.guardianapis.com/search?api-key=f51fa87d-8a55-4fc1-b552-8fa6eb98dee4&section=travel";
                        setTitle("Travel News");
                        basicDefaults();
                        return true;
                    case R.id.itemLifestyle:
                        GAURDIAN_REQUEST_URL = "http://content.guardianapis.com/search?api-key=f51fa87d-8a55-4fc1-b552-8fa6eb98dee4&section=lifeandstyle";
                        setTitle("LifeStyle News");
                        basicDefaults();
                        return true;
                    case R.id.itemEnvironment:
                        GAURDIAN_REQUEST_URL = "http://content.guardianapis.com/search?api-key=f51fa87d-8a55-4fc1-b552-8fa6eb98dee4&section=environment";
                        setTitle("Environment News");
                        basicDefaults();
                        return true;

                    default:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Somethings Wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return true;

                }
            }
        });

        // Initializing Drawer Layout and ActionBarToggle
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.openDrawer, R.string.closeDrawer) {

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                // Code here will be triggered once the drawer closes as we dont want anything to happen so we leave this blank
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                // Code here will be triggered once the drawer open as we dont want anything to happen so we leave this blank

                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);

            }
        };

        //calling sync state is necessay or else your hamburger icon wont show up
        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }
```

PS.- I have tried implementing other methods too like

adding this in apptheme in styles.xml file.

```
<item name="android:activatedBackgroundIndicator">@drawable/drawer_selected_item</item>
```

But still I cant find my solution.
Please help it is the last thing that is left in my project.

Comment: Please refer [link1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30886453/change-the-color-of-a-checked-menu-item-in-a-navigation-drawer), [link2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22374660/navigation-drawer-item-background-colour-for-selected-item) and [link3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23112376/custom-background-color-for-selected-item-with-activatedbackgroundindicator-na) it will help you out.

Comment: @vijaychhalotre I have seen these but still I cant change the background color of selected item.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I have got the solution-

In the NavigationView I did-

```
        app:itemBackground="@drawable/drawer_selected_item"
```

Thus my NavigationView looks like-

```
        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
            app:itemIconTint="@drawable/drawer_item"
            app:itemTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance20"
            app:itemTextColor="@drawable/drawer_item"
            app:menu="@menu/drawer"
            app:itemBackground="@drawable/drawer_selected_item"
tools:context="com.androidexample.newssnips.app.NavigationDrawerFragment" />
```

In the **drawer_selected_item** I modified file as-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@color/colorAccent"/>
<item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

Comment: that's the only solution that worked for me using androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout and com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView :) Thanks.

Comment: What if I want to change textColor as well?

Answer (score 0):

NavigationView has a method called setItemTextColor(). It uses a ColorStateList.`navigationView.setItemTextColor()`. with ColorStateList as a parameter.

Comment: Still not working. But if you can elaborate your answer maybe I may be missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Adding explanation to [Caspian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7034183/caspain)'s answer:

Android Developers Documentation provides ColorStateList so you can play around on different states of a View in android.

Example Code here: [ColorStateList Android Example](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/ColorStateList.html)