# Change background color of selected item in navigation drawer

Tags: java, android, android-layout, navigation-drawer

I want change the blue color of selected item in the navigation drawer.. I can change it when you tap over an item but not in the active item. This is what I use: in the drawable folder

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">  
    <item android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@color/default_color" />
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@color/uva_color" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/uva_color" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@color/default_color" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/default_color" />  
</selector>
```

The color.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="uva_color">#f2f8ee</color>
    <color name="default_color">#f2f8ee</color>
</resources>
```

And then in the layout of nav drawer:

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="260dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/activated_background"
        android:background="#ffff"/>
```

So, the current item selected not change color..any ideas?

EDIT with java nav drawer:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ListView mDrawerList;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
private CharSequence mTitle;
CustomDrawerAdapter adapter;

List<DrawerItem> dataList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

/** Customizzo la actionbar */
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.actionbarcustom);
        //actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        //actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
setTitle("FTV");
int actionBarTitleId = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("action_bar_title", "id", "android");
if (actionBarTitleId > 0) {
    TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(actionBarTitleId);
    if (title != null) {
        title.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    }
}

/**
* Controllo la versione di android, se Kitkat o superiore rendo la nav bar trasparente
* */
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        Window w = getWindow(); // in Activity's onCreate() for instance

        w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION);
        w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);

SystemBarTintManager systemBarTintManager = new SystemBarTintManager(this);
systemBarTintManager.setStatusBarTintEnabled(true);
systemBarTintManager.setStatusBarTintColor(Color.parseColor("#ff3600"));

/*systemBarTintManager.setNavigationBarTintEnabled(true);
systemBarTintManager.setNavigationBarTintColor(Color.parseColor("#CC0000"));*/

    }

// Initializing
dataList = new ArrayList<DrawerItem>();
mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);


mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow,
GravityCompat.START);

// Add Drawer Item to dataList
dataList.add(new DrawerItem(true)); // adding a spinner to the list

dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Preferiti")); // adding a header to the list
dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Avvisi", R.drawable.avvisi));
dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Pianifica viaggio", R.drawable.bus));
dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Mappe e Tratte", R.drawable.maps));
//dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Lables", R.drawable.ic_action_labels));

dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Impostazioni"));// adding a header to the list
dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Settings", R.drawable.settings));
/*dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Cloud", R.drawable.ic_action_cloud));
dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Camara", R.drawable.ic_action_camera));
dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Video", R.drawable.ic_action_video));
dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Groups", R.drawable.ic_action_group));
dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Import & Export",
R.drawable.ic_action_import_export));*/

dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Altro")); // adding a header to the list
dataList.add(new DrawerItem("About", R.drawable.about));
//dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Settings", R.drawable.ic_action_settings));
dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Help", R.drawable.help));

adapter = new CustomDrawerAdapter(this, R.layout.custom_drawer_item,
dataList);

mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open,
R.string.drawer_close) {
public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to
// onPrepareOptionsMenu()
}

public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to
// onPrepareOptionsMenu()
}
};

mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

if (savedInstanceState == null) {

if (dataList.get(0).isSpinner()
& dataList.get(1).getTitle() != null) {
SelectItem(2);
} else if (dataList.get(0).getTitle() != null) {
SelectItem(1);
} else {
SelectItem(0);
}
}

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
// Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
return true;
}

public void SelectItem(int possition) {

Fragment fragment = null;
Bundle args = new Bundle();
switch (possition) {


case 2:
fragment = new FragmentThree();
args.putString(FragmentThree.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition)
.getItemName());
args.putInt(FragmentThree.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID, dataList
.get(possition).getImgResID());

break;
case 3:
fragment = new FragmentOne();
args.putString(FragmentOne.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition)
.getItemName());
args.putInt(FragmentOne.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID, dataList.get(possition)
.getImgResID());
break;
case 4:
fragment = new FragmentTwo();
args.putString(FragmentTwo.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition)
.getItemName());
args.putInt(FragmentTwo.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID, dataList.get(possition)
.getImgResID());
break;
case 5:
fragment = new FragmentThree();
args.putString(FragmentThree.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition)
.getItemName());
args.putInt(FragmentThree.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID, dataList
.get(possition).getImgResID());
break;
case 6:
fragment = new FragmentTwo();
args.putString(FragmentTwo.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition)
.getItemName());
args.putInt(FragmentTwo.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID, dataList.get(possition)
.getImgResID());
break;
case 7:
fragment = new FragmentThree();
args.putString(FragmentThree.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition)
.getItemName());
args.putInt(FragmentThree.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID, dataList
.get(possition).getImgResID());
break;
case 8:
fragment = new FragmentOne();
args.putString(FragmentOne.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition)
.getItemName());
args.putInt(FragmentOne.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID, dataList.get(possition)
.getImgResID());
break;
case 9:
fragment = new FragmentTwo();
args.putString(FragmentTwo.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition)
.getItemName());
args.putInt(FragmentTwo.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID, dataList.get(possition)
.getImgResID());
break;
case 10:
fragment = new FragmentThree();
args.putString(FragmentThree.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition)
.getItemName());
args.putInt(FragmentThree.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID, dataList
.get(possition).getImgResID());
break;
case 11:
fragment = new FragmentOne();
args.putString(FragmentOne.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition)
.getItemName());
args.putInt(FragmentOne.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID, dataList.get(possition)
.getImgResID());
break;
case 12:
fragment = new FragmentThree();
args.putString(FragmentThree.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition)
.getItemName());
args.putInt(FragmentThree.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID, dataList.get(possition)
.getImgResID());
break;  
case 13:
fragment = new FragmentOne();
args.putString(FragmentOne.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition)
.getItemName());
args.putInt(FragmentOne.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID, dataList.get(possition)
.getImgResID());
break;
case 14:
fragment = new FragmentTwo();
args.putString(FragmentTwo.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition)
.getItemName());
args.putInt(FragmentTwo.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID, dataList.get(possition)
.getImgResID());
break;
default:
break;
}

fragment.setArguments(args);
FragmentManager frgManager = getFragmentManager();
frgManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment)
.commit();

mDrawerList.setItemChecked(possition, true);
//mDrawerList.getChildAt(possition).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.activated_background);
setTitle(dataList.get(possition).getItemName());
mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);

}

@Override
public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
mTitle = title;
getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
// Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
// Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggles
mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
// The action bar home/up action should open or close the drawer.
// ActionBarDrawerToggle will take care of this.
if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
return true;
}

return false;
}

private class DrawerItemClickListener implements
ListView.OnItemClickListener {
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
long id) {
if (dataList.get(position).getTitle() == null) {
SelectItem(position);
}

}
}

}
```

This is the standard color in activated item that I DON'T WANT!

[image]

I want this: #f2f8ee

Answer (score 2):

Looks fine...

in your java code that hosts the listview, call `myListView.setItemChecked(position, true);`

Also, the color you set for `state_activated` is the same as when the drawer is in its `normal` state.  Is this intended?...

Create an xml file with a TextView

`nav_drawer_item.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    android:id="@+id/textId"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/[your_selector]" />
```

in `getview()` for your adapter

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { 
    TextView view = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.nav_drawer_item);
    view.setText("whatever_text");
    return view;
}
```

Comment: I have already written that part: `mDrawerList.setItemChecked(possition, true);
  setTitle(dataList.get(possition).getItemName());
  mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);` but still not working :-(

Comment: i want it..i want that activated and selected color are the same.. but now the active color it's the classic blue of android

Comment: ... change `<item android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@color/default_color"` to `<item android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@color/uva_color"`.

Please post a picture of what you have and what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: nothing..still the same blue..now i'm gonna put the picture

Comment: See my edit.  You should inflate a view which uses the drawable instead.

Answer (score 2):

check this sample custom navigation drawer

inside onclick

```
  SelectItem.get(position).setColor(getResources().getColor("your color"));
```

Answer (score 0):

here is how i have done and it is working, the brief **concept** is maintain the **position** of selected item in **adapter** and call `notifyDataSetChanged` on calling `notifyDatasetChanged` the `getView` method is called again and in get view check the position on the selected position change the background view. For details see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22374660/navigation-drawer-item-background-colour-for-selected-item/31697630#31697630) answer.

If you have any confusion please feel free to ask.