# Changing Navigation Drawer Selected Item Color from default blue

Tags: android

Hi and thanks for reading.

I have a problem with my android apps navigation drawer where I cannot change the color from blue - I have went over all the other questions from SO, referred to the android documentation, and have tried everything so far... but still no luck. I really hope someone can help.

The code so far:

**my_background.xml**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Blue still showing up! -->
    <item android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@color/lightPink" />
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@color/lightPink" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/lightPink" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@color/lightPink" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/lightPink" />

</selector>
```

**styles.xml**

```
<item name="android:activatedBackgroundIndicator">@drawable/my_background</item>
```

fragment_navigation_drawer.xml

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/my_background"
    tools:context="com.randompractice.app.NavigationDrawerFragment"

/>
```

I have been stuck on this for 24 hours now and it is driving me crazy. For such a silly little change that my curiosity told me to implement, has turned into a research project. Can anybody see what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 20):

First, I would try removing the android:listSelector attribute, as I don't believe it is necessary.

Next, I would double check you have all these steps:

- In your application's theme, try adding

**themes.xml**

```
<style name="Theme.mytheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:activatedBackgroundIndicator">@drawable/activated_background</item>
</style>
```

- The drawable should refer to a file containing a selector like (like you have)

**activated_background.xml**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/my_color" android:state_activated="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

**colors.xml**

```
<resources>
    <item name="my_color" type="color">#ff0000</item>
</resources>
```

- Finally, make sure you are applying the theme in your manifest's application tag using

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.mytheme"
```

Comment: This should be selected as the right answer, it was the only solution to solve this problem from all what I found during my search.

Comment: This is by far the best answer to this question. Stop messing with `android:listSelector` and do this--it will save you hours of banging your head against a wall.

Answer (score 2):

ListDrawer onItemClickListener:

```
    final CustomListAdapter myadapter;
     mDrawerListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            selectItem(position);
            myadapter.setSelectedItem(position);
        }
```

In custom adapter:

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private final Activity context;
    private final String[] itemname;

    int mSelectedItem;

    public CustomListAdapter(Activity context, String[] itemname ) {
        super(context, R.layout.drawer_list_item, itemname);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        this.context = context;
        this.itemname = itemname;

    }

    public void setSelectedItem(int selectedItem) {
        this.mSelectedItem = selectedItem;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_item, null, true);
        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textitem);
        String iname = itemname[position];
        txtTitle.setText(iname);
        txtTitle.setTypeface(tf);
        if (position == mSelectedItem) {
            txtTitle.setTextColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
        } else {
            txtTitle.setTextColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.normal));
        }
        return rowView;
    }
}
```

In colors.xml

```
    <resources>
        <color name="white">#ffffff</color>
        <color name="normal">#ef3272</color>
   </resources>
```