# Change selection state of Navigation Drawer of the Navigation Support Library

Tags: android, android-fragments, selection, navigation-drawer, state

I am not able to change the background color of the selected item in the navigation drawer as well as the text color of the selected item. I used the code here to create the navigation drawer: [Support Navigation Drawer](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Fragment-Navigation-Drawer).

When I try to change it like [Navigation Drawer item background colour for selected item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22374660/navigation-drawer-item-background-colour-for-selected-item)

It does not work. By default it uses a light grey background and the color of the action menu bar of the normal app screen. Right now I don't think it's possible at all.

Comment: Actually, this is a bug and already reported here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=178697          Now, just wait the new version of the Support Library to be released by Google. Hope in that version will fix this bug.

Comment: I hope that's true and it's indeed a temporary bug. Do you have any idea how frequently these updates occur?

Comment: I found a descent page to get an idea of how often they update here: http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html