# NavigationView theme selected item background style

Tags: android, menu, android-navigationview

I have created an alternative theme for my app which is Dark. I use a navigation bar which is defined as

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
```

It has two groups defined within the menu which are selectable

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/sort_item"
    android:title="One">
    <menu>
        <group
            android:id="@+id/menu_group_sort"
            android:checkableBehavior="single">
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_sort_new"
                android:title="@string/menu_new" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_sort_hot"
                android:title="@string/menu_hot" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_sort_top"
                android:title="@string/menu_top" />
        </group>
    </menu>
</item>

<item
    android:id="@+id/filter_item"
    android:title="Two">
    <menu>
        <group
            android:id="@+id/menu_group_filter"
            android:checkableBehavior="single">
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_category_all"
                android:title="@string/menu_all" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_category_business"
                android:title="@string/menu_business" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_category_technology"
                android:title="@string/menu_technology" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_category_politics"
                android:title="@string/menu_politics" />
        </group>
    </menu>
</item>
```

Normally, the selected item's text is colorPrimary, and the background appears to be some sort of Android grey. When I define my new theme, I use it as such

```
<!-- Dark theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme.Dark" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimaryInverse</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDarkInverse</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccentInverse</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/textColorPrimaryInverse</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/textColorPrimaryInverse</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/textColorSecondaryInverse</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimaryInverse">@color/textColorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondaryInverse">@color/textColorSecondary</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/colorPrimaryInverse</item>

    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/colorAccentInverse</item>
</style>
```

This almost works, everything is styled exactly how I want it except the currently selected item in the NavigationView. Instead, it appears to just be 1 solid block of colorPrimary (no icon, no text), and on the ends is the colorControlHighlight but that's it.

Does anyone know how I can customize a selected item within a NavigationView menu? I've tried every state I could think of, but none worked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't have to customize the style for this one, you can set a [Color State List](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html) to the `NavigationView` `app:itemTextColor`.

---

**Example:**

*NavigationView*:

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/nav_state_list"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_drawer"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_drawer_drawer" />
```

*Create* a `nav_state_list.xml` file in your `res/color` and *put this* inside:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Item checked -->
    <item android:color="#313189" android:state_checked="true" />
    <!-- Item pressed -->
    <item android:color="#318931" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <!-- Item default -->
    <item android:color="#893131" />
</selector>
```

---

This is how it will look after:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the response! This does indeed fix the text color, however the icon is still not appearing next to the text (it does for all non selected items).

Comment: @automaton Try setting this attribute to the NavigationDrawer: `app:itemBackground="@android:color/transparent"`. If that doesn't help, could you post the code where you are changing the selected items?

Comment: Also, take a look to this question, it might help too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22374660/navigation-drawer-item-background-colour-for-selected-item

Comment: That question looks like the right answer, but if you set "android:background" as part of your style it doesn't appear to work for some reason.

Comment: Actually that link does work, but it has to target like this:<item name="android:selectableItemBackground">@drawable/drawer_list_selector_inverse</item>