# Color state list "event" not triggered or handled

Tags: android, android-navigationview

I followed this answer: [NavigationView theme selected item background style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35160827/navigationview-theme-selected-item-background-style) and this one: [Android - Navigation View item menu background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31221637/android-navigation-view-item-menu-background-color)

Consider this navigation view. It uses the color state list `color_state_menu`.

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    app:itemBackground="@color/color_state_menu"
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer_view">
```

This color state list is defined below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@color/colorRoyalRed" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/gray" />
</selector>
```

... in such a way that the current used menu item has a red background, and the others, a gray one.

However, all these menu items always have a gray background. Do you know why?

Comment: Did you also try with `state_checked` like this    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@color/colorRoyalRed" /> ?

Comment: Yes I also tried

Comment: When I click on a menu item, the corresponding fragment is loaded and the clicked menu item's background isn't changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do several things:

1. Use `DrawableStateList` instead of `ColorStateList` - just move `color_state_menu.xml` to `drawable` folder and change

   ```
   app:itemBackground="@color/color_state_menu"
   ```

   to

   ```
   app:itemBackground="@drawable/color_state_menu"
   ```
2. Use `android:state_checked` instead of `android:state_activated`:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
       <item android:drawable="@color/colorRoyalRed" android:state_checked="true" />
       <item android:drawable="@color/gray" />
   </selector>
   ```
3. Add `android:checkable="true"` to each menu item in `drawer_view.xml`

Comment: I didn't think to make the items checkable. Thus I just tried to call `setCheckable(true)` in the navigation view `OnItemClickListener` handler, after what I kept my call to `setChecked(true)` and it works! Thank you! Note that `color_state_menu.xml` can be saved into both `res/color` and `res/drawable` directories (it doesn't matter). Finally, `state_checked` seems indeed to be the good state (I didn't try with `state_activated`).