# Highlight selected item in Navigation drawer

Tags: android, android-layout

I know there are similar questions like this but that's not working for me. I have `listview` in my drawer. I have tried making a selector xml which have `state_activated`,  `state_pressed`,  `state_selected` and this is made background of single row of `listview`. But it's not working as when drawer closed, item gets unselected.  Sorry I can not upload any code as I am asking it through app.

Comment: You can use ripple effect.. but i dont know.. is it possible to apply on listview or not.. bcz till now i only use in recyclerview

Comment: Please go through this : [Navigation Drawer item background colour for selected item](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22374660/navigation-drawer-item-background-colour-for-selected-item)