# How to change the colour of the navigation drawer item

Tags: android

I want to change my navigation drawer list item's background colour to be changed when i click on it.
Also it should change the text and icon colour of that item as well.
Thanks in advance..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Navigation Drawer item background colour for selected item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22374660/navigation-drawer-item-background-colour-for-selected-item)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it setting this attribute to my NavigationView         app:itemBackground="@drawable/drawer_selector"

and my drawer_selector is as below

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/white" />
<item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@color/white" />
<item android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@color/white" />
<item android:drawable="@color/orange" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This is quite simple and is similar to changing the background of any view that you use. You can simply create a method and write all the change code into it. Pass the view as a parameter in the method.

Whenever you click on any of the navigation drawer items, pass your view on the method.

For instance, check this method

```
private boolean viewSelected(View view) {
    ViewHolder currentViewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    KTextView yourtextView = currentViewHolder.yourtextView;
    view.setBackgroundColor(ResourceUtil.getInstance().getColor(R.color.colorSideMenuSelectedBackground));
    currentViewHolder.viewSelector.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    yourtextView.setTypeface(yourtextView.getContext(), ResourceUtil.getInstance().getString(R.string.yourFontName));

    if (lastSelectedView == null) {
        lastSelectedView = view;
        return true;
    }
    if (lastSelectedView != view) {
        ViewHolder oldViewHolder = (ViewHolder) lastSelectedView.getTag();
        oldViewHolder.viewSelector.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        lastSelectedView.setBackgroundColor(ResourceUtil.getInstance().getColor(android.R.color.white));
        KTextView newTextView = oldViewHolder.yourtextView;
        newTextView.setTypeface(yourtextView.getContext(), ResourceUtil.getInstance().getString(R.string.yourfontname));
        lastSelectedView = view;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

This method will simply change the background, font and color of the views.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.

Create two drawable files  : 
1.drawer_background

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:color="checked_background_color" android:state_checked="true" />
<item android:color="default_background_color" />
</selector>
```

2.drawer_text_background

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:color="checked_text_color" android:state_checked="true" />
<item android:color="default_text_color" />
</selector>
```

And add these two properties to your NavigationView ie

```
app:itemIconTint="@drawable/drawer_background"
app:itemTextColor="@color/drawer_text_background"
```

one more if some color is overlapping with some other color

```
  app:itemBackground="@android:color/transparent"
```

Now, All you have to do is to set an item as checked on Click listener of that item to change background and text color. You can do it programmatically.